# About HTTP 1.1 persistent connection and TCP

Tags: http, networking, tcp, connection

When I was introduced to HTTP 1.0 and 1.1, it was emphasized that the main difference was that 1.1 allows a single TCP connection for all of the objects as opposed to 1.0 where a new connection was made for each object download.

My question is, since a connection isn't really continuous but discrete (i.e in packets), then how come each different packet of each object that is being downloaded, doesn't need to go through the ACK, SYN TCP protocol?

How do they all know about the first ACK, SYN that was made? (perhaps made even to a different server than the objects?)

Comment: It sounds like you just don't understand what persistent connections are and should probably just read the HTTP 1.1 specification or read a good page that explains them.

Comment: So reading on persistent connections in the HTTP 1.1 spec should be enough? Any other recommendations? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: You really need to understand something like the OSI model and how networking is layered. [This PDF](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0131014684/samplechapter/0131014684_ch02.pdf) walks you through the layers and gives a web request example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much of your question makes sense. HTTP keepalive only operates on connections to the same target, not 'for all of the objects'. The part about packets doesn't have anything to do with HTTP: you're really asking how TCP works; and the answer to that is that every TCP segment contains the source and destination IP addresses and ports, which are unique to a connection, and a sequence number, for data ordering purposes.

Comment: Maybe an example will make my question clearer, say we want to download two images from a web page (lets call it X), the images are hosted on two different hosts and addresses, so we make the ACK, SYN with X, and then we want to download the two images, why those images don't need another ACK, SYN but can be downloaded directly?

Comment: They can't. The suggestion doesn't make sense. You need a separate connection to each target. HTTP keepalive saves multiple connections *to the same host.*